# Layout changes do not apply in tests

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a button that allows to hide itself and another widget when pressed. When it is hidden, a new button appears on the screen which can undo (show) the previous button and widget again.

I'm pretty sure my implementation for this works because I've tested it on multiple devices without any problems, but whenever I try to write a formal test for it, something goes wrong. I'm using the following code to test my widget:

```
await tester.tap(find.widgetWithText(GestureDetector, "HIDE"));
expect(testContainerState.ifContainerWithOptionsIsDisplayed, false);
print(find.byType(GestureDetector));
await tester.tap(find.widgetWithText(GestureDetector, "SHOW"));
expect(testContainerState.ifContainerWithOptionsIsDisplayed, true);
```

The first two lines are there to tap the button and check whether `ifContainerWithOptionsIsDisplayed` changed. In my implementation, this is done in a `setState` method and should repaint to hide the widget and button and show the new button.
In the third line, I check how many `GestureDetector`s I can still find after what should be a repaint. The output of that `print` statement still shows me that all of the `GestureDetector`s of the widget that should now be hidden are still being found.
In the 4th line, I try to find my SHOW button that should now be visible because of the repaint. But no element is found.

Again, I'm pretty sure the code for my widgets are correct because I've tested this test case manually without any issues. Perhaps I'm missing some knowledge about Flutter tests. Could someone please fill me in?

Comment: Could you try if `await tester.pump();` or `tester.pump();` causes the updates you're missing?

Comment: That fixed it! Any way I can mark this as the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
await tester.pump();
```

or just

```
tester.pump();
```

should do that

See also

- https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/flutter_test/WidgetTester/pump.html
- https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/flutter_test/WidgetTester/pumpAndSettle.html
- https://flutter.institute/flutter-and-widget-tests/

Comment: Great! But I did not get it to work using `tester.pump();` I had to use `await tester.pump(); `.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'd expect `await test.pump();` to be the common case anyway.